# N points with maximum sum distance

Tags: algorithms, graphs, runtime-analysis, computational-geometry, matrices

Given a distance matrix for 50,000 points, how do I select $N$ points so that the sum of all distances between the $N$ points is maximized? $N$ could be as high as 100.

To calculate the sum of distances for all sets of $N$ points would be exponential, which would not scale to 50,000 points.

What is the fastest algorithm that you would know? And also, does this problem have a name? If so, I could do more reading about it.

Thanks very much for your feedback.

Comment: Are these 2D points or what? Is the distance Euclidean?

Comment: Are you familiar with Convex Hull? There are algorithms for computing convex hull in time n log n. Then what?

Comment: See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20030/selecting-most-scattered-points-from-a-set-of-points

Comment: "To calculate the sum of distances for all sets of N points would be exponential". Since  the number of points is upper bounded by a constant, this algorithm requires at most constant time, i.e., it is asymptotically optimal.

Comment: Surely that's not very helpful

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20030/selecting-most-scattered-points-from-a-set-of-points is a different optimization. Here we are interested in the sum of the distances between points, not the area covered. By exponential, I mean exponential in the total number of points.

Comment: As for the number of dimensions, it can be anything. I have changed the question to specify the distance matrix is given.

Comment: The problem is NP-hard, by reduction from maximum clique (consider 0-1 matrix).

Comment: @Dmitry 0-1 matrices don't satisfy the triangle inequality. You could work with 1-2 matrices, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as the [maximum diversity problem](http://grafo.etsii.urjc.es/optsicom/mdp/).